# How to structure database for multilevel packing items

Tags: database-design, packing, inventory-management

I want to make an inventory system where items have multilevel packings e.g A carton has medium boxes , medium boxes has small boxes and small boxes has 2 items. Please tell how to handle it by using sql server 2005 so that it can easily handle sale and purchase and it display exact inventory status of how much carton , medium, small boxes and items are in stock.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) for hierarchical data in a relational database.

Comment: +1 for suggesting nested sets, but please remember that it's not an ideal solution that you should always use for all RDBs - it's a workaround if the database doesn't support heirarchical queries natively.

Comment: That's a good point.  It turns out SQL Server 2005 and later support recursive CTEs.  Thanks for making me aware of this option.  Here's a performance comparison: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/25/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-sql-server/